# AngularJS: app is not defined for a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well, I'm not able to get a controller to work in a simple example which code looks like:

app.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

    // Define AngularJS application
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute'
    ]);


    // Set application routes
    myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/registration', {
            templateUrl: 'views/registration.html',
            controller: 'registrationController'
        }) 
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
         });

    }]);    

})();
```

registration.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

    myApp.controller('registrationController', [
        '$scope',
        '$routeParams',
        '$rootScope',
        '$location', 
        function(
            $scope, 
            $routeParams, 
            $rootScope, 
            $location
        ){


        }
    ]);

})();
```

no clue why but it throws an error

> registration.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: myApp is not defined

Comment: What is the module convention that you are doing here ? why the wrapping functions ?

Comment: This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/Scope_Cheatsheet

Comment: @MarcinMalinowski Simple convention similar to first example from https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide Regarding wrapping I thought I need to use it to get code to work on IE10 (I had issues with another app when it wasn't wrapped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `registration.js`

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
.module('myApp').controller('registrationController', [
    '$scope',
    '$routeParams',
    '$rootScope',
    '$location', 
    function(
        $scope, 
        $routeParams, 
        $rootScope, 
        $location
    ){


    }
]);

})();
```

And the error is pretty much self explanatory. `myApp` is not defined in `registration.js` file. That's why you're getting that error

Comment: Well, that did the job. Didn't know that when wrapped in unnamed function will loose previously defined `myApp` module.